# Reading all the key value pairs from Ignite cache taking long time on slow network

Tags: ignite

I'm reading all the rows from already created Ignite cache having 1M key value pairs.  When I read it from  the same network on which ignite cluster is running, it is taking around 20 second. However, when I read it from a machine, outside the network on which ignite cluster is running, it is taking 10 minutes. The size of whole cache is around 100 MB.  I tried testing the bandwidth between the ignite cluster network and outside network by transferring file of size 100MB. It took only 5 seconds. I am wondering why Ignite is taking whopping 600 seconds to transfer the all key-value pairs from the cache?

//cache configuration

```
CacheConfiguration<BenchmarkCacheStoreKey, OptionalDouble> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<BenchmarkCacheStoreKey, OptionalDouble>();
cfg.setName(cacheName);
cfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
//1 backup of each cache
cfg.setBackups(1);
cfg.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
cfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
cfg.setGroupName(CACHE_GROUP_NAME);
cfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
//do not blockk read/write for cache rebalancing
cfg.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.ASYNC);
```

Logic to read from cache below:

```
Map<K, V> readMap = new HashMap<>();
IgniteCache cache = ignite.cache(cacheName)
cache.forEach(action ->readMap.put(action.getKey(), action.getValue()));
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code to show how you are reading the data from Ignite?

Comment: @Dmitriy update the description with code

Comment: Try to use the Ignite data streamer instead of cache.put(). Simple cache puts will store every value in the standalone message. Data streamer will be able to put all the data in the one batch. Please take a look here:

https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteDataStreamer.html

Comment: @Andrei I'm reading from the cache and storing it into in memory hash map. I don't find any streamer for reading from the ignite cache.

Comment: My fault. I think that you load the data. Could you please provide your cache configuration and information how many nodes you have in your cluster? Did you try to get all entities from the cache or only part of them?

Comment: @AndreiAleksandrov updated the question with cache configuration

Comment: @jayesh Can you try reading in batches using getAll()? Also, you will get much better performance if you group your getAll() keys by partition. This way only one server will have be accessed in order to get a batch of keys.

Comment: @Dmitriy To use getAll(), keys need to be passed as argument. In my use case, I don't know the keys stored in ignite cache.

Answer (score 2):

Try to split you file on 1M parts and transfer it again by parts. I think this time you would have result similar to 10 minutes.

> cache.forEach(action ->readMap.put(action.getKey(),
>   action.getValue()));

forEach does scan query, by default scan query has page size == 1024, you can try to increase it, it will increase batching size, you can do it like this:

```
cache.query(new ScanQuery<>().setPageSize(10_240));
```

It's a cluster solution, all defaults are configured to work in the same network, so if you have bad network and run client in different cluster than server, then you might need to tweak it.
However, instead of moving data to client, it's better to send compute task to server and return some small result to client if this possible.

Comment: I have played with multiple page size. However no improvement in throughput. loading 128*1024 entries is taking around 64 second on client running on slow network while it is taking around 2 second on client running on cluster.

Comment: In this case, data transfer is expensive operation compare due to high network latency, please consider to move calculation to a server instead of moving data to client: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid